# Distributing $n$ elements into $5$ groups. What is the probability that one of the groups is disproportionately large or small.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We have $n$ elements that we distribute randomly (uniformly and independently) into $5$ groups. What is the probability that at least one of the $5$ groups have been assigned less than $15\%$ of n items or more than $25\%$ of $n$ items.

Im sorry if this is an obvious question, but I can't even figure out how to structure the problem in such a way to find another solution online.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's often best to just simulate questions like this.  That offers the advantage that you can easily vary the assumptions.  Approximate methods for particular cases are, of course, available, but it can be hard to vary those.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to consider this for $n$ sufficiently large, and perhaps an approximation is good enough for your purposes.

If we pick one of the five groups, then its size follows the binomial distribution, ie., its expected size if $\frac 15n$ and standard deviation is $\sqrt{n\frac15\frac45}=\frac25\sqrt n$. Then "less than 15% or more than 25%" corresponds to "deviation by more than $\frac1{20}n$ in either direction", i.e., "deviation by more than $\frac18\sqrt n$ standard deviations in either direction". From this you should be able to determine the (small) probability $p$ that the picked group is "bad". Note that $p$ is also the expected number of bad groups provided by the picked group. Hence the expected number  of bad groups in total is $5p$. As "badness" of different groups is not independent, this is only an **approximation** to the probability of at least one bad group.